# Combine Two Folders with Smart Folder

Tags: finder, macos, smart-folders

Okay, so one thing I've wanted to be able to do for ages now in OS X is to create or view a combined Applications folder that displays the contents of both `/Applications` and `~/Applications` (assume it exists).

Now, I know LaunchPad can do this, but I'd still like to be able to do this in a regular Finder window, for example using a Smart Folder.

Is this possible, and if so, what are the steps for doing this (either in the Finder itself, or via command line)?

I've experimented for searches of my entire computer for all Applications, however this only returns the application bundles themselves, ignoring any enclosing folders. Really I just want top level items for each of the applications folders; for example, I'd like to see the `/Applications/Utilities` folder, not its contents.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to make Smart folder like physical folder with the combined contents of two folders](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/66135/how-to-make-smart-folder-like-physical-folder-with-the-combined-contents-of-two)

Comment: I'm not certain this is a true duplicate, or at least the other issue is happy to accept solutions I'm not sure really fit what I'm asking; creating links via a script for example feels a very messy way to do this. Do smart folders still lack any means of combining results (e.g - an OR) for two searches?

Comment: I've actually found a capability in `mdfind` that kind of covers this; I can do `mdfind -onlyin /Applications -onlyin ~/Applications 'kind:App'` which at least combines the results, but there's no obvious way to do this as a smart folder.

Answer (score 0):

check the code below and I will explain

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>CompatibleVersion</key>
    <integer>1</integer>
    <key>RawQuery</key>
    <string>(((kMDItemKind == "Application"cd &amp;&amp; ! ( ((kMDItemDisplayName == "*aam*"cd || kMDItemAlternateNames == "*aam*"cd) || (kMDItemDisplayName == "*aas*"cd || kMDItemAlternateNames == "*aas*"cd) || (kMDItemDisplayName == "*lic*"cd || kMDItemAlternateNames == "*lic*"cd) || (kMDItemDisplayName == "*uninstall*"cd || kMDItemAlternateNames == "*uninstall*"cd) || (kMDItemDisplayName == "*setup*"cd || kMDItemAlternateNames == "*setup*"cd) || (kMDItemDisplayName == "*install*"cd || kMDItemAlternateNames == "*install*"cd)) ))))</string>
    <key>RawQueryDict</key>
    <dict>
        <key>FinderFilesOnly</key>
        <false/>
        <key>RawQuery</key>
        <string>(((kMDItemKind == "Application"cd &amp;&amp; ! ( ((kMDItemDisplayName == "*aam*"cd || kMDItemAlternateNames == "*aam*"cd) || (kMDItemDisplayName == "*aas*"cd || kMDItemAlternateNames == "*aas*"cd) || (kMDItemDisplayName == "*lic*"cd || kMDItemAlternateNames == "*lic*"cd) || (kMDItemDisplayName == "*uninstall*"cd || kMDItemAlternateNames == "*uninstall*"cd) || (kMDItemDisplayName == "*setup*"cd || kMDItemAlternateNames == "*setup*"cd) || (kMDItemDisplayName == "*install*"cd || kMDItemAlternateNames == "*install*"cd)) ))))</string>
        <key>SearchScopes</key>
        <array>
            <string>/System/Applications</string>
            <string>/Applications</string>
            <string>/Users/USERNAME/Applications</string>
        </array>
        <key>UserFilesOnly</key>
        <false/>
    </dict>
    <key>SearchCriteria</key>
    <dict>
        <key>FXCriteriaSlices</key>
        <array>
            <dict>
                <key>criteria</key>
                <array>
                    <string>com_apple_RawQueryAttribute</string>
                    <integer>104</integer>
                </array>
                <key>displayValues</key>
                <array>
                    <string>Raw query</string>
                    <string>(kMDItemKind == "Application"cd &amp;&amp; ! ( ((kMDItemDisplayName == "*aam*"cd || kMDItemAlternateNames == "*aam*"cd) || (kMDItemDisplayName == "*aas*"cd || kMDItemAlternateNames == "*aas*"cd) || (kMDItemDisplayName == "*lic*"cd || kMDItemAlternateNames == "*lic*"cd) || (kMDItemDisplayName == "*uninstall*"cd || kMDItemAlternateNames == "*uninstall*"cd) || (kMDItemDisplayName == "*setup*"cd || kMDItemAlternateNames == "*setup*"cd) || (kMDItemDisplayName == "*install*"cd || kMDItemAlternateNames == "*install*"cd)) ))</string>
                </array>
                <key>rowType</key>
                <integer>0</integer>
                <key>subrows</key>
                <array/>
            </dict>
        </array>
        <key>FXScopeArrayOfPaths</key>
        <array>
            <string>/System/Applications</string>
            <string>/Applications</string>
            <string>/Users/USERNAME/Applications</string>
        </array>
    </dict>
</dict>
</plist>
```

If you see the key SearchScopes then there you can add what paths to include.

So simple as that - then it can be done. To learn this I used HoudaSpot that saved it for me so I could learn how to set it up. So basically just open a pre-saved .savedSearch file and edit the contents with SearchScope key.

Comment: Can you add some details about the file you are showing, how to create one, where to find it etc.?

Comment: You need to create a shared folder and save it. For OP's use case, search for `Kind`  = "Application" and save. Then, open the saved smart folder with a text editor and add the array of directories to the `SearchScopes` key. The solution worked for me.